# reloadTimelineForComplication on watchOS 3

Tags: ios, xcode, watchos, watchos-3

In watchOS 2 when users make some activities in the Watch App we use reloadTimelineForComplication to reload the data in the complications. But in watchOS 3 it doesn't work. CLKComplicationServer find activeComplications, but when we call reloadTimelineForComplication nothing happens.
How reload the data from the watchOS app in the complications now?

Comment: For me ```- (void)reloadTimelineForComplication:(CLKComplication *)complication;``` works in watchOS 4. Can you provide some of your code?

Comment: Maybe your execution time is exhausted. Consider the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/clockkit/clkcomplicationserver/1627891-reloadtimelineforcomplication) :

>If your complication has already exceeded its allotted daily budget for execution time, calls to this method do nothing. Call this method sparingly. If your existing complication data is still valid, method instead.